# flexbox and specified width

Tags: css, flexbox

I trying to get a container in which each item have the same size except when a class which specify the size is added to an item. In this case the item takes the width of the added class and the other item divide equitably the left space.
I create an auto class which is used by all item.
flex-grow: 1; which allow the item to grow flex-shrink: 1; allwo to reduce and flex-basis: auto; to gives all items the same size but when I added small class with a width of 5% it didn't work

```css
.flex-container {
  background-color: #F4F7F8;
  resize: horizontal;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  margin: 1em;
}

.auto {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-basis: auto;
  border: 5px solid black;
}

.small {
  width: 5% !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="item auto small">small</div>
  <div class="item auto">auto</div>
  <div class="item auto">auto</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reset the `flex-grow` for this class:

```css
.flex-container {
  background-color: #F4F7F8;
  resize: horizontal;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  margin: 1em;
}

.auto {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-basis: auto;
  border: 5px solid black;
}

.small {
  flex-grow: 0;
  width: 5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">

  <div class="item auto small">small</div>
  <div class="item auto">auto</div>
  <div class="item auto">auto</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

just set `max-width` in `.small` class.

```css
.flex-container {
    background-color: #F4F7F8;
    resize: horizontal;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    margin: 1em;
}
.auto {
    
        flex-grow: 1;
        flex-shrink: 1;
        flex-basis: auto;
         border: 5px solid black;
}


/*or set with flex basis*/

.small {
  flex: 0 0 50%;  
  max-width: 50%;  
}

.without-max {
  flex: 0 0 50%;  
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">

   <div class="item auto small">small</div>
   <div class="item auto">auto</div>
   <div class="item auto">auto</div>

</div>


<div class="flex-container">

   <div class="item auto without-max">smallsmallsmallsmallsmallsmallsmallsmallsmallsmallsmallsmallsmallsmallsmallsmallsmallsmallsmallsmallsmall</div>
   <div class="item auto">auto</div>
   <div class="item auto">auto</div>

</div>
```

Comment: max-width is useless in this case

Comment: @TemaniAfif bootstrap use this technique.  I think they are smarter than us.

Comment: @soniamaklouf i already added an answer ;) ... and it's not about bootstap smarter or not, simply remove it and see the difference

Comment: but if you want to play with width then flex-basis is better.  `The flex-basis CSS property specifies the initial main size of a flex item.`